# ONNX serializing torch models that take strings as inputs

Tags: serialization, torch, onnx

Are there any examples of ONNX serializing torch models that take strings as inputs?

Putting a random type as `args` in the `torch.onnx.export` function yields:

```
RuntimeError: Only tuples, lists and Variables supported as JIT inputs/outputs. Dictionaries and strings are also accepted but their usage is not recommended. But got unsupported type numpy.ndarray
```

but there's also the explanation under the `args` definition that:

```
                                  ... Any non-Tensor arguments will
        be hard-coded into the exported model; any Tensor arguments
        will become inputs of the exported model, in the order they
        occur in args.  If args is a Tensor, this is equivalent
```

so is there a way to serialize a model like this:

```py
model('hello world')
Out: [0.8, 0.2]
```